# I Am Trying To Understand... AJAX/PHP Help

Tags: php, ajax

I am working on a simple click/attack game. Here's my code...

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"  />
    <title>Random Number Game</title>
    <script src="rand.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="p_wrap">

        <div id="p_attack"></div>


        <form name="fight">

            <div class="submit">

                <input class="att_button" type="submit" value="Attack!" onclick="randNum();" />

            </div>

        </form>

        </div>

        <div id="c_wrap">

            <div id="c_attack"></div>

        </div>

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
   *, body { margin:0; padding:0; }
body { background:url(rand_bg.png) center top repeat-x; }
div { position:relative; }

#wrapper { width:600px; margin:7em auto; display:block; }

#p_wrap { width:200px; height:100px; padding:20px 0; display:block; overflow:hidden; float:left; background-color:#09C; -moz-border-radius:3px; -webkit-border-radius:3px; -khtml-border-radius:3px; -moz-box-shadow:-1px 2px 5px #999; -webkit-box-shadow:-1px 2px 5px &#999; -khtml-box-shadow:-1px 2px 5px #999; }
#c_wrap { width:200px; height:100px; padding:20px 0; display:block; overflow:hidden; float:right; background-color:#F00; -moz-border-radius:3px; -webkit-border-radius:3px; -khtml-border-radius:3px; -moz-box-shadow:1px 2px 5px #999; -webkit-box-shadow:1px 2px 5px &#999; -khtml-box-shadow:1px 2px 5px #999; }


#p_attack { width:100%; height:20px; padding:10px 0 0; text-align:center; font-size:18px; }
#c_attack { width:100%; height:20px; padding:10px 0 0; text-align:center; font-size:18px; }

.submit { top:20px; text-align:center; margin-bottom:20px; }
.att_button { padding:5px; background-color:#09C; cursor:auto; outline:none; }
```

JS:

```
    // JavaScript Document
function randNum()
{
  document.getElementById("p_attack").innerHTML="";
  return;
  document.getElementById("c_attack").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("p_attack").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById("c_attack").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","mt_rand.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

PHP:

```
  <?php

$att = mt_rand(0,100);
$p_att = mt_rand(0,100);
$c_att = mt_rand(0,100);

if ($att == 100)
        echo $att.": Critical!";
    elseif ($att >= 50)
        echo $att.": Hit!";
    elseif ($att == 0)
        echo $att.": Epic Fail!";
    else
        echo $att.": Miss!";

?>
```

Here's where I'm at... the two extra variables in the PHP script are going to take the place of the simple elseif and be comparative, so as one side can "win". However, right now, I'm simply trying to figure out the most efficient way to parse the $p_att and $c_att to the two corresponding divs through AJAX onclick. If anyone could help explain this to me, that'd be awesome. Thanks, guys.

p.s. The ampersands in the CSS is to keep the pound sign from making the font size 400.

Comment: You can use the buttons on top of the input box (like {} for code) to format your post. I've fixed it up a bit for you, please check your output (it's below the input box) if you want to see what's going on the next time :)

Comment: I did use the code brackets. Apparently, this site has problems in the chrome version I'm using. Thank you, though, the formatting looks a lot better.

Comment: it is suggested to use Prototype AJAX framework / jQuery to perform HTTP requests.

Comment: It may be, but I'm trying to learn how this stuff works. That way when I step into using the frameworks, I'll understand them.

Answer (score 0):

```
a slightly better php part

<?php 
    $att = mt_rand(0,100);
    $p_att = mt_rand(0,100);
    $c_att = mt_rand(0,100);

    if($att==100){echo $att.": Critical!";}elseif ($att == 0){echo $att.": Miss!";}else{
        if($p_att > $c_att){
            echo $att.": Player Hit Comp! Win"; 
        }else{
            echo $att.": Comp Hit Player! Lose"; 
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: lol. Thanks Lawrence. I just threw the php together, it's going to become comparative later. I'm just having problems getting the info to the divs like I want, THEN, I can fix my php up.